# Finding E[X|Y=y] when integrals don't seem to converge

Tags: probability, statistics

The joint density of X and Y is given by f(x,y) = 6xy(2-x-y); 0≤x, y≤1. Calculate the expected value of X given Y=y.

Answer in book: $\frac{2.5-2y}{4-3y}$

**What I have so far**

E[X|Y=y] = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp_X(x|y) dx $

So $p_Y(y)$ = $\int_{0}^{\infty}6xy(2-x-y)) dx $ = 0

This stops me from finding $p_X(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}$

and E[X|Y=y] = $\int_{0}^{\infty}x\frac{f(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}) dx$

I'm not sure what do to because of the infinite limits. It'd back sense if the book said 0≤x≤y≤1, but it splits them up into the ones above. How is it even possible to solve this?

Comment: Where do you get your $P_Y(y)$ from the function given?  Generally, when a density function is given over a range, it's assumed to be zero outside that range, so either (a) you shouldn't be using infinite limits on your integrals, or (b) you should be using those limits to integrate a function that's explicitly zero outside the domain specified - which amounts to essentially the same thing.

Comment: The densitly is defined by the given expression for $0\le x \le 1$ and $0\le y \le 1$ and is zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(Y=y) = \int_0^1 6xy(2-x-y) dx= 4y -3y^2$

\begin{align}
E[X|Y=y] &= \int_0^1 \frac{x*P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{6x^2y*(2-x-y)}{4y-3y^2} dx \\
&= \frac{2.5-2y}{4-3y}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

When your book says $0\le x,y\le 1$, what is means is $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le y\le 1$. The comma is supposed to indicate that both $x$ and $y$ fall in the range $[0,1]$. We know that your first interpretation, $0\le x$ and $y\le 1$, can't be correct since $f(x,y)$ has to integrate to 1, and integrating any polynomial over the entire plane will either be undefined or infinite.

Unfortunately, this is just one of the common abuses of notation mathematicians like to use.